# Is there a log of Ethereum Trading Volume for a given currency over time?

Tags: ether, exchanges, markets

I know [CoinMarketCap lists daily trading volumes for multiple currencies](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/#markets), but how do we access a log of these volumes for a given currency over time?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any historical logs, but you could grab the live data yourself.

One way to do this would be to use the [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/), call it yourself at defined intervals, and process the data however you like.

Specifically, use the ticker for Ethereum:

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/
```

Then get the volume per currency by adding the appropriate query string. e.g. ETH/IOTA pair:

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=MIOTA
```

Gives:

```
[
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "465.152", 
        "price_btc": "0.039602", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1199850000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "44727531235.0", 
        "available_supply": "96156807.0", 
        "total_supply": "96156807.0", 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.77", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-0.52", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-2.55", 
        "last_updated": "1512514456", 
        "price_miota": "123.121374543", 
        "24h_volume_miota": "317589048.839",    <-------- 24-hour volume
        "market_cap_miota": "11838958288.0"
    }
]
```